# Joomla 3.x - How to create article from frontend which is by default "featured" and "published"?

Tags: joomla, frontend, default

I am using Joomla 3.4 and want to provide group of users with possibility to create article (I need it to be by default PUBLISHED and FEATURED) but when they create new article it is NOT PUBLISHED and NOT FEATURED (users do not have possibility to change this setting in the fronted). 
I am using standard joomla component - create article - when users are logged in they can add an article but than I have to login into admin modul and set "featured" and "published" when article is created.

I have tried to change
/joomla/administrator/components/com_content/models/forms/article.xml 
AND
/joomla/components/com_content/models/forms/article.xml

I have set default=1 (featured=YES) but it does not work for me. Moreover in the article.xml article should be by default published but it is not.

Answer (score 0):

add this:

```
if(!isset($data['state']))
    $data['state']=1;
if(!isset($data['featured']))
    $data['featured']=1;
```

to /joomla/administrator/components/com_content/models/article.php on save function.for example:

```
public function save($data)
{
    if(!isset($data['state']))
        $data['state']=1;
    if(!isset($data['featured']))
        $data['featured']=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, setting Featured to **default=1** in */joomla/components/com_content/models/forms/article.xml* saved my day. All new articles are featured now by default.

This file is regularly overwritten by Joomla upgrades, so the correct override file has to be copied to:
*/templates/system/forms/com_content/article.xml*